# Count of bounty question has been toggling

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounties, private-beta

I am participating on pets private beta. Today a user added a 200 reputation bounty on his question. We all know that the question will appear in the featured tab. Since the bounty has been added, the count of questions in the featured tab has been changing from 0 to 1.

[image: bounty error]

As in the picture, there is a question with a bounty and yet it shows 0

Soon enough it will change to 1 then again to 0 (while the bounty is still on the question).

What is the cause of this?

Comment: caching? Half the bugs on meta are a result of caching :/

Comment: @hjpotter92 Speaking of which: [Caching.](http://cdn.meme.li/i/p2619.jpg)

Comment: @hjpotter92 half?? I'd say 120% of the bugs!

Comment: @hjpotter92 Or localisation.

Comment: @michaelb958 or jQuery

Comment: @ColeJohnson I see you're trying to blame jQuery for a problem with SE. You should totally drop that and try jQuery. *(I'm sorry. I just had to. Besides, jQuery is never the problem; it is the **solution**.)*

Comment: @michaelb958 I see you're trying to blame jQuery for a problem with jQuery. You should totally drop that and try SE.

Comment: I've experienced this dozens of times.  I don't think it can be blamed on caching, since it sometimes occurs long after the bounties are started.