# Having one featured question shows as zero featured questions in the featured tab

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bountied-tab

A question had a bounty applied to it in Gamification.SE, however it still shows '0 featured' in the tabs, regardless of whether it was viewed on the front page or in the tab itself.

[image]

I can reproduce this on multiple browsers, even after cleaning cache/cookies/etc. I installed Opera for the first time just to check this - still reproducible.

Comment: Pretty sure this question has been asked before. Can't find it though - it has to do with caching.

Comment: @JoshC I asked the question. This is it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200512/count-of-bounty-question-has-been-toggling

Comment: I see a 1 featured there.